# Issue using drop() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, drop

I'm new to python and I'm using pandas to perform some basic manipulation before running a model.

Here is my problem: I have got dataset A and I want to create another dataset (B) equal to A, except for one variable X.
In order to reach this outcome I'm doing this:

```
A = B
columns_drop= ['X']
B.drop(columns_drop,axis=1)
```

But the result came out to be that both A and B misses the variable X.

Comment: Use `A = B.copy()`, both A and B point to the same object otherwise.

Comment: just to explain - by doing this ```A = B``` you create another name for the same variable. It's called "call by reference", not "by value". https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-python-call-by-reference-or-call-by-value/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
A = B.drop(columns_drop, axis=1)
```

This will make a copy of the data.

Your approach failed as both `A` and `B` point to the same object. The proper way to make an independent copy is `A = B.copy()`, although the non-mutables objects like lists that are in the dataframe won't be deep copied!